# How Threads are able to access Synchronized block which are supposed to be block?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I have written the below Java program. This program is creating three threads and started them all :

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {

        int count = 0;
        while (true) {                

                System.out.println("" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                if (count == 20 && Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("Thread-1")) {
                    try {                        
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(100000000);                        
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }//while ennds here
    }//run ends here
}//class ends here


public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        t1.setName("Thread 1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        t1.setName("Thread 2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyThread());
        t1.setName("Thread 3");        

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }

}
```

Second thread goes on sleep after some time.

As the run method is synchronized, it is supposed to be accessed only by one thread at a time.

Sleep method never releases the lock on the object. But here once the "Thread 1" goes to sleep, after that "Thread 2" and "Thread 3" are successfully able to access the same method and continue there execution.

Can anybody explain that what is happening here ? execution should be on hold after "Thread 1" goes on sleep according to the concept of sleep.

Comment: I am by far no expert, but you are using 3 different objects (all created with new) - this could be the reason why.

Comment: I think you are right :)

Comment: You have to lock the same resource, not the same method on different resources.

Comment: @KshitijJain the `count` has to be `volatile` and `static` and declared outside the method run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `synchronized` is on an instance method. It will only be `synchronized` if you were calling the method on the same instance. You aren't doing that. You're calling the `run()` method on 3 different instances.

Answer (score -1):

If you want have synchronization for all threads you need to use some static field.
It could be monitor (simple Object used with synchronization) or Lock

```
private static final Lock LOCK = new ReentrantLock();

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        LOCK.lock();

        // Your code

    } finally {
        LOCK.unlock();
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `static` field. It just needs to be a shared reference.